# How to get an auto-scrolling textfield over the keyboard?

Tags: flutter

How do I make the second text field scroll automatically over the keyboard as it reaches the keyboard, so that none of the text gets hidden behind it, and no I can not use a scaffold.

Here's my widget,

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
        height: 650,
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
          child: Card(
            color: Palette.backgroundColor,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            ),
            elevation: 4,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    reverse: true,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                      itemCount: 3, // Number of widgets in the ListView
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        if (index == 0) {
                          return IconButton(
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                          );
                        } else if (index == 1) {
                          return TextField(
                            controller: _title,
                            maxLines: null,
                            maxLength: 40,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Title (optional)',
                            ),
                          );
                        } else if (index == 2) {
                          return TextField(
                            minLines: 16,
                            maxLines: null,
                            maxLength: 4000,
                            controller: _text,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Start jotting down things here...',
                            ),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Container(); // Placeholder for any additional items
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      GradientButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        width: 120,
                        child: const Text('Save'),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => setState(() => isFav = !isFav),
                        icon: isFav
                            ? const Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.pink)
                            : const Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => setState(() => isLock = !isLock),
                        icon: isLock
                            ? const Icon(
                                Icons.lock,
                                color: Colors.yellow,
                              )
                            : const Icon(Icons.lock_open),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (note == null) Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.delete,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[Here's a screenshot of the output I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqGjR.png)

I've tried using ListView as well its the same result. It scrolls but some of the text is still behind the kayboard.